# Hosting on google drive

Tags: web-hosting

I'm new to web developing and had to design a website for college. I decided to make it from scratch. I am currently hosting the website on Google Drive and it's working fine. Does this mean that it will work fine on a hosting company's web server? The main reason I ask is because of the many errors I get when using Markup Validation!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google drive hosting changes in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302170/google-drive-hosting-changes-in-url)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of variables involved in this decision. The main assumption I'll make is that it's a flat site with no server scripting involved. If that's the case, you shouldn't have any issues copying them over to another web server. Though you [should fix up those Markup Validation errors](http://www.websitecleanup.com/html_validation_errors.php).

When I mention server scripting, I'm referring to PHP/ASP/Coldfusion/etc code that may be in your pages.

Comment: Then there shouldn't be issues, just respect your directory structure. If you're loading the files within a sub-directory of a domain, you'll want to be careful with absolute references. Like if you push your files to http://www.example.com/example/ and on your html page you have it loading `/css/main.css`, then it will reference http://www.example.com/css/main.css instead of http://www.example.com/example/css/main.css, so you will need to account for that.